# Exact computation and plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am plotting a function using the following code.

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.misc import comb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
X = np.arange(2,N)

def k_loop(w,n):
    K = np.arange(0, w+1)
    return (comb(w,K)*(comb(w,K)/2**w)**(3*float(n)/np.log(n))).sum()

def w_loop(n):
    v = [comb(n,w)*k_loop(w,n) for w in range(1,n+1)]
    return sum(v)

Y = [w_loop(n) for n in X]
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

However I would like to be sure that there are no numerical errors. Is it possible for get python to do the computation exactly and only translate to floating point at the last moment when plotting? The log can't be exact but I would like to keep everything else exact as long as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the calculations to be as exact as possible with base-10 numbers, try using the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

This will require a rewrite of your code, though.

- `decimal` has a `ln` and `log10` functions, and a `power` function.
- but you will probably have to rewrite `comb` in terms of `decimal`s, or use `exact=True` and cast the result to `decimal`.